# Add Categories To Custom Post

Tags: posts, categories, customization

I'm using a theme that uses a custom post type called Albums to create an archive of (strangely) albums consisting of a media player and brief bio. What I need however, is to be able to either duplicate the post type and call the second one Singles or to add a category option to both the Post page and the archive.

I've asked the theme developer and they won't help. I'm at a dead end.

I can provide pages if necessary.

Many Thank Yous

Andy

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your post type is registered as albums, you can add a custom taxonomy to the post type as follows:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_album_taxonomy' );

function create_album_taxonomy() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'albumtype',
        'albums', // content type here
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Album Type' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'albumtype' ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
        )
    );
}
```

Place this in your functions.php. Hope this helps

Comment: Sadky, this has made no difference to either the Archive page or the Post editor. 

Thanks though Svaarband

Comment: Pleasure, this should work in adding categories (taxonomy) to the custom post. You would just need to modify the archive etc. but I take it that you don't have a lot of development experience?

Comment: I can understand and follow, but this is a bit beyond me off the top of my head..

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add the `taxonomies` parameter in the `register_post_type()` function for that particular custom post type. Below is an example snippet:

```
...
register_post_type( 'albums', array(
  ...  
  'taxonomies'          => array( 'category' ),
  ...
) );
...
```

Take a look yourself, hope this was helpful for you.

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Answer (score 0):

I've read through the codex a couple of times and I'm really not following. Here's the Post-Type code, it doesn't seem to follow

```
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('media-block'); ?>>
<?php if(get_field('alb_link_external')): ?>
<a target="_blank" href="<?php echo get_field('alb_link_external'); ?>">
<?php else: ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<?php endif; ?>
    <div class="holder">
        <div class="image"><?php the_post_thumbnail( array(216,216) ); ?></div>
        <div class="text-box">
            <i class="media-decoration media-audio fa fa-headphones"></i>
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <?php if(get_field('alb_release_date') != '') : ?>
            <time class="datetime" datetime="<?php echo date( 'c', strtotime( get_field('alb_release_date') ) ); ?>"><?php echo __("Release date", IRON_TEXT_DOMAIN); ?> <?php the_field('alb_release_date'); ?></time>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```